# Text in div moves upwards when button in the same div is removed using AngularJS ng-if

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div which contains some text and a button.

When I click on the button, it disappears based on a criteria which is controlled by an ng-if, but this causes the text to move up a couple of px!

I can't seem to make it stay in the same spot. Any ideas?

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="review-helpful">
  <span ng-if="showThis">Howdy there partner!</span>
  <span ng-if="!showThis">How they hanging?</span>
  <button ng-if="showThis" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-helpful" ng-click="setShowThis(false)">Yes</button>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.review-helpful {
    margin-top: 5px;
    min-height: 23px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #696969;
}

.btn-helpful {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I've hooked up a plnkr to show the exact problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/9FqzhB3NJXHHnHtdfVvB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the button is greater than the height of the text in the span.

There are probably a million ways to solve it. One way is using the `line-height` style:

```
.review-helpful {
    margin-top: 5px;
    min-height: 23px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #696969;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```